# Errno::EINVAL: Invalid argument - setenv

Tags: chef-infra

I have a chef recipe which used to run fine till yesterday night and suddenly started to fail with this weird error "Errno::EINVAL: Invalid argument - setenv"

Could it be related to Chef-Server? Has any one faced this before.

Here is the code that is throwing.

```
hash2.each do |key,value|

daaskey = "#{key.to_s}".gsub(/\s|"|'/, '')

daasvalue = "#{value.to_s}".gsub(/\s|"|'/, '')

**ENV[daaskey] = daasvalue**

end
```

Comment: Why are you setting env variables in chef?

Answer (score 2):

Usual cause of that error is trying to set `ENV['']`, which in this case means `key` is empty. Track down why that would be.